# Ansible Fetch Quote Error

Tags: fetch, ansible

I am trying to retrieve a file from a remote host. However, after looking at some examples on stackoverflow, the bottom two methods result in the follow errors:

```
- shell: ls -f ubuntu_s*
  register: file_name
- fetch: src=/home/ubuntu/{{file_name.stdout_lines}} dest=/home/user   


 - shell: ls -f ubuntu_s*
      register: file_name
    - fetch: src={{item}} dest=/home/user
      with_items: "{{file_name.stdout_lines}}"
```

Error:

```
ERROR! this task 'fetch' has extra params, which is only allowed in the following modules: command, shell, script, include, include_vars, add_host, group_by, set_fact, raw, meta

The error appears to have been in '/home/user/BuildPkg.yml': line 49, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

      register: file_name
    - fetch: src=/home/ubuntu/{{file_name.stdout_lines}} dest=/home/user
      ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"


The error appears to have been in '/home/user/BuildPkg.yml': line 49, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

      register: file_name
    - fetch: src=/home/ubuntu/{{file_name.stdout_lines}} dest=/home/user
      ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"
```

Both approaches give the same error. What seems to be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to avoid `shell` where possible. Modules – this is the Ansible way.
If you need to get a list of files from remote host and fetch them:

```
- find:
    pattern: ubuntu_s*
    path: /home/ubuntu/
  register: myfiles
- fetch:
    src: "{{ item.path }}"
    dest: /home/user
    flat: yes
  with_items: "{{ myfiles.files }}"
```

Comment: this worked great! Just a note, if you want to transfer larger files add become:no to this

Comment: @latencybit for large files there's also `synchronize` module

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is looping over file globs, like:

```
- fetch: src={{ item }} dest=/home/user 
  with_fileglob:
    - ubuntu_s*
```

Note: [know what you may face](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) whenever trying to parse ls output

Comment: Keep in mind that `with_fileglob` expands on **local Ansible host**! This will not work for collecting list of files from remote host.